# Task Decomposition

Tags: c, multithreading, task, scheduled-tasks

So I am trying to understand how task decomposition works and why it doesn't seem to increase the speed up of my calculation. So I have made a parallel system that simply sorts arrays. With just using 4 threads, I get quite a decent speed up but when I implement task decomposition, it doesn't seem to speed up my calculation and I do not understand why.

So for my system, I have created a Task Queue for each thread. Each thread then begins to calculate each task, one by one, until it's stack is empty. At this point, instead of having the threads wait for all other threads to finish, the thread with an empty stack will search to find a stack that has tasks and steal from it - effectively maximizing the amount of work that every thread can do.

But the issue is that, although I get a speed up, it is very minimal and I cant seem to figure out why. Could it possibly be that the time that the threads are waiting is so minimal that it barely affects the computation time? Or that the time needed to access other thread stack's negates most of the speedup from stealing tasks on other stacks?

Here are my results for you can see what is going on:

```
    parallel_for (1 Thread)    parallel_for (4 Threads)   parallel_for (4 Threads) + Task Decomposition
1         seg fault                    seg fault                   seg fault
10        21.993                       seg fault                   seg fault
100       21.7294                      5.42989                     seg fault
1000      21.5556                      5.2258                      5.38024
10000     21.5513                      5.43617                     5.3735
100000    21.6238                      5.4557                      5.41096
1000000   21.5447                      5.9712                      5.9325
10000000  21.5898                      10.8605                     10.753
```

You can ignore the seg faults (its just due to not enough space on stack) and the values on the side are just the side that each thread is dividing the array to compute by - it shouldnt be a factor in why the task decomposition provides a minimalistic amount of speedup.

Comment: Q: What platform?  Q: What compiler?  Q: Have you done any analysis (including [profiling](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gnuprof.html)) to locate bottleneck(s)?

Answer (score 0):

No, no, *NO*, no, no!

Simply adding threads will NOT speed anything up UNLESS:

1) The tasks are completely independent (maybe they are, maybe they aren't)

2) Each task can be allocated to its *OWN CPU* (or core)

3) The cost of managing the thread is small compared to the actual work being performed by the task.

SUGGESTION:

If you're using "gcc", try running "gprof" to determine exactly where the bottlenecks might be in your implementation.  Also make sure that your threading library (e.g. pthreads) is taking advantage of all the CPUs/cores on your workstation:

- [GPROF Tutorial – How to use Linux GNU GCC Profiling Tool](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial/)
- [PThreads Overview](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

PS: Much will depend on:

a) your OS (Linux?  Mac?  Windows?)

b) your compiler (GCC? MSVC?)

c) Your threading library

Comment: Each thread has it's own core. The thing is that once the thread has finished all task's on it's own stack, it will seek to find tasks on other stacks and perform them. Why would that not increase performance? I am utilizing the threads to the fullest

Comment: Yes - if a task that would otherwise be blocked on one thread can instead run on a different thread (that you're *sure* is running on a different core) - then that *would* increase performance.  Again: if there's a possible bottleneck, you should definitely *profile* your application.  What the bottleneck could be - or what tools can assist in profiling - depend entirely on your platform (Linux?  Windows?) and compiler (GCC?  MSVC? CLang?)